# Authentication with PHP SDK

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I am having trouble using the PHP SDK for authentication. The effect I am trying to get is whene a user visits the site if they are loged in with FB they see "Logout" which loggs them out when clicked but if they are not logged in when they arrive they should see "You need to log in with FB" which loggs them in. The effect I am currently getting is that the site displays the "You need to log in with FB" even if the user is already logged in, whene this is clicked the user is taken to facebook.com with an error message displayed reading "An error occurred. Please try later". Im sure I must be missing something in my code but cant figure out what, I am fairly new to FB development. Please see my code below. Any help much appriciated.

```
<?php

require_once("facebook.php");


$user = $facebook->getUser();



  $config = array();
  $config[‘appId’] = xxx;
  $config[‘secret’] = '{secret}';

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);



$fbparams = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
  'redirect_uri' => 'xxx'
);



session_start();



$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($fbparams);
$params = array( 'next' => 'xxx' );
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); 




    if(!$user)
        {
            echo "<P>You need to <a href=\"{$loginUrl}\">log into FB</a></p>\n";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "<p style=\"margin-bottom:20px;\"><a href=\"{$logoutUrl}    \">Logout</p>\n";


            }

?>
```

Comment: Please reset your secret key on your app immediately!

Comment: There's also no need to hide the App ID, it's public information.  It's the secret key that you need to protect  :)

Comment: Not sure but could the problem be with the getUser()? It seems that $user is not set, is this correct?

Comment: I played with PHP code once in 2003...I'm not too good at it.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<?php

require_once("facebook.php");
$user = $facebook->getUser();

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = xxx;
$config[‘secret’] = '{secret}';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$fbparams = array(
'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
'redirect_uri' => 'xxx'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($fbparams);
$params = array( 'next' => 'xxx' );
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); 

<?php if ($user) { ?>
<p><a href="<?=$logoutUrl?>">Logout</a></p>
<?php } else { ?>
  <p><a href="<?=$loginUrl?>">Click here to View Your Stalker of the Day</a></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not call $facebook before creating the instance, This code should work:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array();
$config[‘appId’] = xxx;
$config[‘secret’] = '{secret}';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user = $facebook->getUser();


$fbparams = array(
'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
'redirect_uri' => 'xxx'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($fbparams);
$params = array( 'next' => 'xxx' );
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); 

if(!$user)
    {
        echo "<P>You need to <a href=\"{$loginUrl}\">log into FB</a></p>\n";
    }
else
    {
        echo "<p style=\"margin-bottom:20px;\"><a href=\"{$logoutUrl} }\">Logout</p>\n";


        }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have tried both mothods but I am still getting the same result. Could it maybee have something to do with the "redirect_uri" as I am specifying the current url by means of "http://xxx.com/index.php" for both the logon and logout?

Comment: Whene I echo $user it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = array( 'next' => 'xxx' );
```

is deprecated SDK, use

```
$params = array( 'redirect_uri' => 'xxx' );
```

instead.